# Select query With Order Localized Caharacters

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I use Sqlite on Android with Android Studio.

Select * From MyTable ORDER BY MyStringField COLLATE LOCALIZED
returns correct order with local characters.

On ios i use Xcode 13 and swift.sqlite
But there is no LOCALIZED option on queries.
There is Binary option which is not working.
Returns strings which are starting with local characters returns at the end.

How do i perform language specific collation on sqlite.swift on ios

Regards

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution? I'm having the same issue and I need COLLATE LOCALIZED in my queries on iOS. It's working fine on Android.